# Can I throttle downloads in Firefox 12?

Tags: firefox, download, throttling

How can I throttle my downloads in Firefox 12?

Like a global setting, "Maximum download speed: 20kbps". And thereby every download would share that maximum download pool of 20kbps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the addon [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/), it has options to throttle speeds.

Comment: Doesn't work with current DownThemAll and current Firefox, it seems. (26.11.2019)